# Why to use our own Offset Repository for Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

I am currently trying to configure Kafka for a project. I am a bit confused regarding the offset repository. I know the two out of the box options are storing in Kafka or Zookeeper, I also found out that there is another option (at least if we use kafka in combination with Apache camel) that I can also define and initialise my own repository anywhere on the file system.

**My question is: is there any scenario where offset repository stored in Kafka or Zookeeper is not persistent or consistent? I am mostly concerned about the situation where any part of the system (consumer, producer, kafka instance or zookeeper instance) shuts down unexpectedly. Once those components are restarted, will the consumer get the offset where it stopped reading from the topic?**

**Does explicit Repository on a shared volume/storage makes any sense?**

Please let me know if anything is unclear in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the offset near the application and set an offset value to start consuming records from Kafka. It all depends on what you want to do.

> is there any scenario where offset repository stored in Kafka or Zookeeper is not persistent or consistent?

I can't remember any at the moment.

> I am mostly concerned about the situation where any part of the system (consumer, producer, kafka instance or zookeeper instance) shuts down unexpectedly. Once those components are restarted, will the consumer get the offset where it stopped reading from the topic?

It depends on the configuration of your application. If your application crashes once it can't connect to Kafka and the application is configure to start consuming from `EARLIEST`. You will start consuming the earliest records available on that topic.

It will restart from the last offset read (and commited) if you use `LATEST`.

If you want to skip to the latest record saved in a topic you need to tell your consumer that..

```
#example
//seek to end of the topic
consumer.seekToEnd();
```

Please find more details about it in Confluent website and Apache Kafka website.

Comment: "It will restart from the last offset read (and commited) if you use LATEST."
Is this also not dependent on the session? If the consumer is restarted, imo the info what was committed should also be lost. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you chose to Kafka  store your offsets and if you are using the same consumer group to consume data from the same Kafka topic: it will not be lost.

Comment: You can make a small experiment on your machine. Install Kafka and play around with Kafka consumers and producers.

Produce 1 message to a topic, restart Kafka, and try to consume again using the same consumer group to that same topic.